# Calculate Exponential Moving Average using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, technical-indicator

I want to calculate the exponential moving average (**EMA**) for a set of price data using Pandas.
I use the formula from [this article](https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-calculate-the-ema-of-a-stock-with-python) as well as the test data from its example calculation to validate my results:

[image]

I found some previous posts that suggest using `ewm` and `mean` for this. Following the example data from the article mentioned above, the attempt would be something like this for **EMA(5)**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10, 11, 11.5, 10.75, 12, 11.75, 12.25, 14, 16, 17, 15.6],columns=["price"])
df["ema_5"] = df.price.ewm(span=5, min_periods=5, adjust=False).mean()
```

Unfortunately, the results do not match the expected values for index 4 and onwards.

Therefore, I tried a more "manual" approach that follows the described formula, where I first calculate the **SMA** (simple moving average) for the first ever **EMA** (index 4) and then use the formula for every succeeding item.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10, 11, 11.5, 10.75, 12, 11.75, 12.25, 14, 16, 17, 15.6],columns=["price"])
df.loc[4, ["ema_5"]] = df.loc[:4, "price"].mean()
df.loc[5:, ["ema_5"]] = (df["price"] * (2/6)) + (df["ema_5"].shift(1) * (1 - (2/6)))
```

This attempt provides me the expected **EMA(5)** values for index 4 and 5 but it does not continue calculating for index 6 and onwards. How can I apply this formula to every item beyond index 5?

Comment: Why did you set `span=5`? According to the docs, you should be setting `alpha=your_smoothing`.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, we need to perform a rolling calculation in which we need, for the calculation of each `exponential moving average (EMA)`, the **previous** `EMA` that was just calculated. I personally do not know of (and could not find) any `pandas` built-in functionality that allows to perform a calculation according to the aforementioned requirement. I thought of 2 solutions of how to achieve this:

- **`.apply()` combined with an `ema` calculator defined as a `class`:** A `class` allows us to define an attribute which stores the previously calculated `EMA` result. We can combine that with a method inside the class that uses `.apply()` to achieve the desired outcome. The `class` `EMACalculatorPandasOnly` shows how this can be done.
- **Using a `for loop` accelerated by [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/):** Usually, people advise against using `for loops` to iterate over every row of a `DataFrame` as it's notoriously slow. However, this is not the case when combining it with `numba`. In fact, this approach is much faster than `.apply()` and the use of a `numba`-enhanced `for loop` is also mentioned in the [`pandas` guide about enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#pandas-numba-engine). This approach also does not require us to define a `class`.

The code below shows how you can use the two methods as well as their respective results (both give you the desired outcome). Further below you can find their definitions. When you set `factor` to a large number such as `1_000_000`, you scale your dataset and you'll be able to see the difference in performance - for a factor of `1_000_000` your dataset contains 11 million rows and the `apply()` method required in my environment about 1 minute while the `numba for loop` less than 1 second.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

factor = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[10, 11, 11.5, 10.75, 12, 11.75, 12.25, 14, 16, 17, 15.6] * factor,
    columns=["price"]
)

# instantiate class using .apply() internally
ema_calculator = EMACalculatorPandasOnly(
    window_size=5
)

df['ema_pandas'] = ema_calculator(
    df=df,
    price_colname='price',
    tar_colname='ema_result'
)

# Approach 2: numba for loop

df['ema_numba'] = calculate_ema_numba(
    df=df,
    price_colname='price',
    window_size=5
)

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Results:

```
|   price |   ema_pandas |   ema_numba |
|--------:|-------------:|------------:|
|   10    |     nan      |    nan      |
|   11    |     nan      |    nan      |
|   11.5  |     nan      |    nan      |
|   10.75 |     nan      |    nan      |
|   12    |      11.05   |     11.05   |
|   11.75 |      11.2833 |     11.2833 |
|   12.25 |      11.6056 |     11.6056 |
|   14    |      12.4037 |     12.4037 |
|   16    |      13.6025 |     13.6025 |
|   17    |      14.735  |     14.735  |
|   15.6  |      15.0233 |     15.0233 |
```

Definition of the two approaches:

```
# Approach 1
class EMACalculatorPandasOnly:
    """Important: This approach implicitly assumes df contains a pandas.RangeIndex."""
    def __init__(self, window_size, smoothing_factor=2):
        
        self.sma_at_start = None
        self.smoothing_factor = smoothing_factor
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.previous_ema = None


    def __call__(self, df, price_colname, tar_colname):
        
        self.sma_at_start = EMACalculatorPandasOnly.calculate_sma_at_start(
            df=df,
            price_col=price_colname,
            window_size=self.window_size
        )
        result_df = df.copy(deep=True)
        result_series = result_df.apply(
            lambda row: self.calculate_ema_rowwise(
                row=row,
                price_col=price_colname
            ),
            axis=1
        )

        return result_series

    def calculate_ema_rowwise(self, row, price_col):
        
        if row.name < self.window_size - 1:
            # assign NaN to row
            ema = np.NaN
        elif row.name == self.window_size - 1:
            # assign simple moving average to row with index == window size
            ema = self.sma_at_start
            self.previous_ema = ema
        else:
            # compute exponential moving averages according to formula
            ema = (
                (
                    row[price_col]
                    * (self.smoothing_factor / (self.window_size + 1))
                )
                + (
                    self.previous_ema
                    * (1 - (self.smoothing_factor / (self.window_size + 1)))
                )
            )
            self.previous_ema = ema

        return ema


    @classmethod
    def calculate_sma_at_start(cls, df, price_col, window_size):

        upper_index = window_size - 1
        sma_at_start = df.loc[:upper_index, price_col].mean()
        
        return sma_at_start


# Approach 2
def calculate_ema_numba(df, price_colname, window_size, smoothing_factor=2):

    result = calculate_ema_inner(
        price_array=df[price_colname].to_numpy(),
        window_size=window_size,
        smoothing_factor=smoothing_factor
    )

    return pd.Series(result, index=df.index, name="result", dtype=float)


@jit(nopython=True)
def calculate_ema_inner(price_array, window_size, smoothing_factor):
    result = np.empty(len(price_array), dtype="float64")
    sma_list = list()
    for i in range(len(result)):

        if i < window_size - 1:
            # assign NaN to row, append price to simple moving average list
            result[i] = np.NaN
            sma_list.append(price_array[i])
        elif i == window_size - 1:
            # calculate simple moving average
            sma_list.append(price_array[i])
            result[i] = sum(sma_list)/len(sma_list)
        else:
            # compute exponential moving averages according to formula
            result[i] = (
                (
                    price_array[i]
                    * (smoothing_factor / (window_size + 1))
                )
                + (
                    result[i-1]
                    * (1 - (smoothing_factor / (window_size + 1)))
                )
            )
        
    return result
```